# Acumatica: Sales Order custom calculation inconsistency

Tags: customization, acumatica

With some help and a lot of trial and error I was able to create a customization that allowed for the following:

1. "Total Profit" field on the Sales Order summary area
2. "GP %" field on the Sales Order summary area
3. "Total Profit" field on the Sales Order details area (by line)
4. "GP %" field on the Sales Order details area (by line)

Total Profit = Ext. Price - Ext. Cost
GP % = (Total Profit / Ext. Price) * 100

The calculation for these four fields works some of the time, but I have noticed when I commit the line either by entering a new line or with Control + Enter, and then go back and change the Ext. Cost, the Total Profit and GP% don't update. Even when I save and refresh it does this. The only time it seems to work 100% is when I enter it in very methodically going one step at a time. But this is not how the out of the box totals are calculated. It doesn't matter which order you enter in your quantity, price, etc. - the out of the box totals always update. How do I make my four custom fields like this in Acumatica?

SOLine Custom fields (each field separated by a blank line):

```
[PXDBCurrency(typeof(SOLine.curyInfoID), typeof(SOLineExt.usrTotalProfit))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Profit", Enabled = false)]
[PXFormula(typeof(Sub<SOLine.curyLineAmt, SOLine.curyExtCost>))]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<SOOrderExt.usrCuryOrderTotalProfit>))]

[PXDBDecimal(4)]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]

[PXFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<SOLine.curyLineAmt, Equal<decimal0>>, decimal0>, Div<SOLineExt.usrTotalProfit, SOLine.curyLineAmt>>))]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]

[PXUIField(DisplayName = "GP %", Enabled = false)] 
[PXFormula(typeof(Mult<SOLineExt.usrGPPercent, decimal100>))]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
```

SOOrder Custom fields (each field separated by a blank line):

```
[PXDBCurrency(typeof(SOOrder.curyInfoID), typeof(SOOrderExt.usrOrderTotalProfit))] 
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total Profit", Enabled = false)] 
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]

[PXDBDecimal(4)]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]

[PXFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<SOOrder.curyOrderTotal, Equal<decimal0>>, decimal0>, Div<SOOrderExt.usrOrderTotalProfit, SOOrder.curyOrderTotal>>))]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]

[PXUIField(DisplayName = "GP %", Enabled = false)] 
[PXFormula(typeof(Mult<SOOrderExt.usrOrderGPPercent, decimal100>))]
```

Comment: Can you provide source code for your solution? Include all custom DAC fields and attributes you used.

Comment: Gabriel - I updated my original post. Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: If your company has support subscription, I recommend that you create a case for Acumatica Support. This can significantly speed up the solution of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

PXFormula should have no problems with DAC extensions and custom fields. It's really hard to tell what the issue is by looking only at field attributes. Please, at least, update your code snippet with DAC field declarations, so it becomes more clear what attributes belong to what field.

Comment: it actually looks like it's working.the only issue right now looks like the order level gross profit percent calculates initially and displays a correct percentage, but then disappears… This is very strange. Any idea why this might happen? My formulas are working just fine but something is going on with this one field. Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: another thing--the  percentage  is displaying with 12 decimal places. Any idea how to change it 2? Also, any idea how to bold font in Acumatica on the screen? I just want to change specific fields, not everything

Comment: I figured out the decimal place and bold font thing.now I just need to figure out why the gross profit percent is disappearing. Any ideas?